# Regex to remove leading zero for any ipv6 address

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

How can I remove leading zeros from any ipv6 address.

`String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("((?::0\\b){2,}):?(?!\\S*\\b\\1:0\\b)(\\S*)", "::$2");`

It's compressing to this form.

```
2001:0DB8:0:0:0476:: --> 2001:0DB8::0476::
```

but it should remove leading zero such as:

```
2001:DB8::476::
```

What do I need to change in the above regex?

Comment: Do you need 2001:DB8:::476::
 or  2001:DB8::0476::   ?

Comment: i need 2001:DB8::476:: , leading zero should be removed from everywhere!!

Comment: If you remove leading zeros the result is  2001:DB8:::476:: , right ?

Comment: yes,but using this regex its not working.
how to do that?

Comment: @Sujith For 2001:0db8:0:0000:00:000:0002:0000 --->2001:db8:::::2:
which is not a valid ipv6 address.
it should be 2001:db8::2:0:0.
Only first grouped zero need to be removed not all,your regex is removing all zero and replacing with ":".
leading zero is working fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44881/discussion-between-sachin-grover-and-sujith-ps)

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a simple solution :

```
String subjectString="2001:0DB8:0:0:0476::";
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(:(0)*)|(^0+)",":");
System.out.println(resultString);
```

The result will be :

```
 2001:DB8:::476::
```

Comment: it giving as :2001:DB8:::476::,  : before 2001 which is not valid.but leading zero its removing.

Answer (score 1):

```
.replaceAll("(^|[^0-9A-Fa-f])0+([0-9A-Fa-f])", "$1$2")
```

will remove leading zeroes from runs of digits.

Obviously this will do bad things to numbers with decimal points or myriad separators as in `"1,002,003.04"`.

---

If you want to remove not just leading zeroes from a non-zero number, but also `0`, then you can use a simpler regex:

```
"2001:0DB8:0:0:0476::".replaceAll("\\b0+", "").equals("2001:DB8:::476::")
```